# Can I create a new event hub in an existing namespace through arm template?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-eventhub, azure-rm-template

I have created a namespace through arm-template now can I create an event hub in that namespace through arm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-event-hubs-create-event-hub-and-consumer-group/azuredeploy.json), or more specifically this snippet:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
    "name": "[concat('namespaceName_in_which_you_want_your_eventHub', '/', 'eventHubName')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/EventHubs",
    "properties": {},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the detailed template for creating event hub using ARM in existing namespace, You just need to send required parameter-

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "namespaceName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "eventHubLocation": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "eventHubName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "consumerGroupName": {
        "defaultValue": [                
            "social"                
        ],
        "type": "array"
    },
    "SenderPolicy": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "ReceiverPolicy": {
        "type": "string"
    }
},
"resources": [
  {
    "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces",
    "sku": {
      "name": "Standard",
      "tier": "Standard"
    },
    "name": "[parameters('namespaceName')]",
    "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
    "location": "[parameters('eventHubLocation')]"
  },
  {
    "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('namespaceName'),'/',parameters('eventHubName'))]",
    "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
    "properties": {
      "path": "[parameters('eventHubName')]",
      "messageRetentionInDays": 7,
      "partitionCount": 4
    },
    "dependsOn": [
      "[concat('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/', parameters('namespaceName'))]"
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs/consumergroups",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('namespaceName'),'/',parameters('eventHubName'),'/',parameters('consumerGroupName')[copyIndex()])]",
    "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
    "copy": {
      "name": "consumerGroupName",
      "count": "[length(parameters('consumerGroupName'))]"
    },
    "properties": {},
    "dependsOn": [
      "[concat('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/', parameters('namespaceName'), '/','eventhubs','/',parameters('eventHubName'))]"
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs/authorizationRules",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('namespaceName'),'/',parameters('eventHubName'),'/',parameters('SenderPolicy'))]",
    "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
    "properties": {
      "rights": [
        "Send"
      ]
    },
    "dependsOn": [
      "[concat('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/', parameters('namespaceName'), '/','eventhubs','/',parameters('eventHubName'))]"
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs/authorizationRules",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('namespaceName'),'/',parameters('eventHubName'),'/',parameters('ReceiverPolicy'))]",
    "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
    "properties": {
      "rights": [
        "Listen"
      ]
    },
    "dependsOn": [
      "[concat('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/', parameters('namespaceName'), '/','eventhubs','/',parameters('eventHubName'))]"
    ]
  }
]
```

}

Hope it helped.